# Error: Failed to invoke 'addComment' due to an error on the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a regular application. One of his options is to leave a comment. When you click on the Post button, an error will pop up. Error: Failed to invoke 'addComment' due to an error on the server.
The connection to the hub has been established.
Also in the configuration settings, SingalR was added and endpoints to the hub were installed.
How fix it?

Index.cshtml

```
@model Blog111.Models.BlogViewModels.PostViewModel
@{
   Layout = "_HomeLayout";
   ViewData["HeaderImage"] = $"../../UserFiles/Blogs/{Model.Post.ID}/HeaderImage.jpg";
   ViewData["HeaderTitle"] = Model.Post.Title;
   ViewData["AuthorName"] = $"{Model.Post.Creator.FirstName} {Model.Post.Creator.LastName}";
   ViewData["PostDate"] = Model.Post.Update.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
   ViewData["AuthorId"] = Model.Post.Creator.Id;
}

<article>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            @Html.Raw(Model.Post.Content)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <h3 class="mb-5">@Model.Post.Comments.Count() Comments</h3>
            <ul class="comment-list comment-top" list="@Model.Post.Comments" count="0" id="comlist">
                @foreach (var comment in Model.Post.Comments.Where(comment => comment.Parent is null))
                {
                    <li class="comment" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            <h4 class="commenter-name">@comment.Poster.FirstName @comment.Poster.LastName</h4>
                            <div class="comment-date">@comment.Create.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:tt")</div>
                            <p class="comment-message">@comment.Content</p>

                        </div>


                    </li>
                    <hr />
                }
            </ul>
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <input asp-for="Post.ID" readonly hidden id="postId" />
                        <input asp-for="Comment.Poster.FirstName" readonly hidden id="uF" />
                        <input asp-for="Comment.Poster.LastName" readonly hidden id="uL" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                            <textarea asp-for="Comment.Content" class="form-control" rows="3" required id="content"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary post-btn" id="send">Post</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <a class="reply-btn btn" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" asp-route-ReturnUrl="~/Post/@Model.Post.ID">Login to comment this Post</a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</article>
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/sendComments.js"></script>
```

sendComments.js

```
"use strict";
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/comments").build();
document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;

connection.on("addComment", function (post, user, message) {
console.log("asdasdasd");
var item = "<div class=\"comment-body\"><h4 class=\"commenter-name\">".concat(user).
    concat("</h4>").concat("<div class=\"comment-date\">").concat(date).concat("</div>").concat("<p class=\"comment-message\">")
    .concat(message).concat("</p>").concat("</div>");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = item;
document.getElementById("comlist").appendChild(li);
});
connection.start().then(function () {
document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
var uF = document.getElementById("uF").value;
var uL = document.getElementById("uL").value;
var post = document.getElementById("postId").value;
var user = uF.concat(uL);
var message = document.getElementById("uF").value;

connection.invoke("addComment", post, user, message).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
event.preventDefault();
});
```

CommentsHub.Cs

```
using Blog111.Data;
using Blog111.Entities;
using Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Services.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blog111.Hubs
{
public class CommentsHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IPostService postService;
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    ApplicationDbContext db;

    public CommentsHub(IPostService postService, UserManager<User> userManager, ApplicationDbContext <User> db)
    {
        this.postService = postService;
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
   public async Task addComment(int postId, string user, string message)
    {
        string first = user.Split(' ')[0];
        string second = user.Split(' ')[1];
        Comment comment = new Comment
        {
            Post = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(post => post.ID == postId),
            Poster = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.FirstName == first && user.LastName == second),
            Create = DateTime.Now,
            Content = message
        };
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("addComment", postId, user, message);
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of invoked function. Your Hub method and invoked function with same name may be thats why you have this error.